# Make Custom Url In codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

**Model**

```
function get_footer_pages(){
    $query=$this->db->where('section','footer');
    $query=$this->db->get('pages');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        $result=$query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
function get_url($row){
    $title=$row['title'];
    $not_allowed=array('/','?','\"','&','"',':','%','\'',',');
    $title=str_replace($not_allowed,'',$title);
    $title=str_replace(' ','-',$title);
    $title=$title."_".$row['id'];
    return $title;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$data['footer_pages']=$this->Home_model->get_footer_pages();
```

**View:**

```
<?php foreach($footer_pages as $f_pages){ ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $f_pages['url'] ?>"><?php echo $f_pages['name'] ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to create a `url` combination of `title` and `id` as i performed in function `get_url()`.

**Now problem:**

is how can i call this `get_url()` in `get_footer_pages()` to make the url of all the results of `get_footer_pages()` and use this url in my `VIEW` in `href`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this function throughout all of your views, it would be better to place it in helper (and make sure you autoload that helper). Then, in your view you'll have:

```
<?php foreach($footer_pages as $f_pages){ ?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo get_url($f_pages) ?>"><?php echo $f_pages['name'] ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

This would generate the url on the fly - whenever you need to display it, instead of generating all urls at once and then iterating again through them in order to display them in the view.

Now that you have your urls in the footer, you need to handle them properly. First, you need to create a route in your routes file that will catch the wanted urls and pass them to the controller that's supposed to handle the action. You haven't specified that part, so here is an example based on which you can create your own routes.

```
$route['product/:num'] = 'catalog/product_lookup/$1';
```

What this does is when the app receives a request like `example.com/product/1`, it actually calls the `product_lookup` function of `catalog` controller and pass `1` as the function argument.

Comment: your means i have to create a file any name in helper folder, and then `get_url()` save in helper file. and call that function in my view?

Comment: Yes. And you will need to add that helper file to the helpers autoload array in your `application/config/autoload.php` file.

Comment: if i perform all functionalities of `get_url()` in my view,  then?

Comment: Please check the answer about how the view would change.